# input onfocus problem

Tags: php, html

it is the problem, i can't undertand anyway.
i have the following simple script

---

```
    <input class="input"  type="text" name="l_username" style="color: #ccc;" 
     value= " <?if ($_POST[l_username] != '') 
              echo $_POST[l_username];
              else echo 'something';?>"   
     onfocus="if (this.value == 'something') {
 this.value='';this.style.color='black';}" />
```

onfocus doesn't work here, but when i delete php script from value, it works

---

```
<input class="input"  type="text" name="l_username" style="color: #ccc;" 
         value= " something"   
         onfocus="if (this.value == 'something') {
     this.value='';this.style.color='black';}" />
```

it works fine.
could you tell me why?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input class="input"  type="text" name="l_username" style="color: #ccc;" 
 value= " <?if ($_POST[l_username] != '') 
          echo $_POST[l_username];
          else echo 'something';?>"   
 onfocus="if (this.value == 'something') {
this.value='';this.style.color='black';}" />
```

you have a space in front of your PHP script. Try to remove it to match the javascript if case (`if (this.value == 'something'`)

Answer (score 1):

```
 " <?if ($_POST[l_username] != '') 
              echo $_POST[l_username];
              else echo 'something';?>"
```

because of the space character before <?

In your focus event handler you could use the defaultValue property, so you don't have to repeat the "something" string twice

```
onfocus="if(this.value === this.defaultValue){this.value='';this.style.backgroundColor='black';}"
```